# How can I query whether a value lies before or after a range?

Tags: postgresql, range

I have a Postgres range and a value, and want to be able to determine if the value lies before, within, or after the range.

Determining if the value lies within the range is trivial:
`SELECT '[1,10]'::int4range @> 3; -- t`

But looking at [range functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-range.html), the `@>` operator is the only one I see that doesn't require both operands to be ranges, so determining whether the value lies before or after the range is not as straightforward.

I'm currently constructing a trivial range to represent my value (inclusive endpoints, both equal to the value), and then using `<<` (strictly left of) and `>>` (strictly right of):

`SELECT '[1,10]'::int4range << '[11,11]'::int4range; -- t`
`SELECT '[1,10]'::int4range >> '[-3,-3]'::int4range; -- t`

This works, but having to construct this trivial range representing a single discrete value just so I can use the `<<` and `>>` operators feels a bit kludge-y to me. Is there some built-in function or operator I'm overlooking that would allow me to do these queries using the value directly?

I considered and rejected an approach based on using `lower(range) > value` and `upper(range) < value`, as that doesn't account for the inclusivity/exclusivity of the range's bounds.

I'm using Postgres 9.6.5, but it doesn't look like anything has changed in this regard in Postgres 10.

Answer (score 3):

> I [...]  rejected an approach based on using lower(range) > value and upper(range) < value, as that doesn't account for the inclusivity/exclusivity of the range's bounds.

I am not sure what you mean with that. `lower()` and `upper()` **do** account for inclusive/exclusive: `lower('(1,10]'::int4range);` returns 2 and `lower('[1,10]'::int4range);` returns 1

It seems to me creating an operator for this would be quite easy:

Create two functions to compare an int to an int4range:

```
create function int_smaller_than_range(p_value int, p_check int4range)
  returns boolean
as
$$ 
   select p_value < lower(p_check);
$$
language sql;

create function int_greater_than_range(p_value int, p_check int4range)
  returns boolean
as
$$ 
   select p_value > upper(p_check);
$$
language sql;
```

Then create the operators:

```
create operator < (
  procedure = int_smaller_than_range,
  leftarg = int, 
  rightarg = int4range,
  negator = >
);

create operator > (
  procedure = int_greater_than_range,
  leftarg = int, 
  rightarg = int4range,
  negator = <
);
```

This can now be used like this:

```
select 4 > int4range(5,10); -> false

select 4 < int4range(4,10,'[]'); -> false

select 4 < int4range(4,10,'(]'); -> true 

select 5 > int4range(4,10,'[]'); -> false

select 11 > int4range(4,10,'[]'); -> false 

select 11 > int4range(4,10,'[)'); -> true
```

Comment: Ah, it looks like for ranges of discrete data types (int4, date) lower/upper do take into account inclusive/exclusive.  That works for my purpose, because my data type is discrete.  If however the data type is instead continuous (numeric, tsrange), it looks like lower/upper may not be a good choice:

`SELECT lower('(2.4, 3.4)'::numrange); -- 2.4`